# Write a class support for yield keywords in Scala

Tags: scala

How can I make a class support `for` keywords in scala?
e.g:

```
class A(data: String) {
  ...
}

val a = A("I'm A")
for {
  data <- a
} yield {
  data
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler rewrites all `for` comprehensions into the necessary constituent parts: `map()`, `flatMap()`, `withFilter()`, `foreach()`. That's why many Scala syntax rules are suspended inside the `for` comprehension, e.g. can't create variables in the standard fashion, `val x = 2`, and can't throw in `println()` statements.

In your example, this will work.

```
class A(data: String) {
  def map[B](f: (String) => B) = f(data)
}

val a = new A("I'm A")
for {
  data <- a
} yield {
  data
}  // res0: String = I'm A
```

But note that if you have multiple generators (the `<-` is a generator) then only the final one is turned into a `map()` call.  The previous generators are all `flatMap()` calls.

If your `for` comprehension includes an `if` condition then you'll need a `withFilter()` as well.

I recommend avoiding `for` comprehensions until you have a good feel for how they work.

Comment: Hi, It works.Could you give some reference about `for` with `map(), flatMap(), withFilter(), foreach()`? There are too many magic for me now.

Comment: [Chapter 23](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html) from [PiS](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/) touches on the subject. Also, [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDaw2yXAa50), by Josh and Dick, is well worth the time investment.

Comment: really helpful!I think it will be better If Scala give a trait for the `for` keyword.